# Is it possible to dynamically change the path of the formula references using Python in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, xml

We are at the point of a file share migration, where we have quite a few excel files that contain formulas, referencing the old file share address.

Is it possible, to dynamically change all formulas containing a reference to the old file share to the new file share?

If possible could you provide me with some python code to achieve this?

```
Q:\general\2021\[excel_file.xlsm] # Old filepath

I:\general\2021\[excel_file.xlsm] # New filepath
```

Comment: (1) how does the link in the excel file look like? (the one one u share is the file path.. not the formula) (2) is this file share migration happens every month.. or only once in every 5-10 years? if this is intend to be a 'one-time-chg' a Ctrl+H on all excel file should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you need just to replace some text in all cells on the first sheet of the file `test.xlsx`. It can be done this way:

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(r"d:\temp\test.xlsx")

sheet = wb.Sheets(1)
sheet.Cells.Replace("Q:\\general\\2021\\", "I:\\general\\2021\\")

wb.Save()
wb.Close()
```

If you have many sheets and many xlsx files you can add loops to read all files and all their sheets:

```
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client

folder = Path.cwd()                  # current folder
files = list(folder.rglob("*.xlsx")) # all xlsx files from the folder and subfolders

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

for f in files:                      # loop through all files
    wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f)

    sheets = wb.Sheets
    for i, sh in enumerate(sheets):  # loop through all sheets
        sh = wb.Sheets(i+1)
        sh.Cells.Replace("Q:\\general\\2021\\", "I:\\general\\2021\\")

    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
```